# spliting a concatenated text column into binary columns in R (dplyr) when a list of all categories is not known

Tags: r, dplyr, concatenation, tidyr

I have seen similar questions to mine but I could not find a good solution to mine yet in `tidyr` and `dplyr` . I have a concatenated column of different text categories where I don't know a complete list of them. It is big data and I could not identify all categories in this column. I need to split them all for each `ID` and create a corresponding binary column indicating if that category is lined with the `ID` .
this is a sample of the data

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                   number=c("a,b,d","e,a","c","","k,t"))
df %>% glimpse()
```

```
Rows: 5
Columns: 2
$ id     <dbl> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
$ number <chr> "a,b,d", "e,a", "c", "", "k,t"
```

my desired data will be like

```
id a b C d e k t
1  1 1 0 1 0 0 0
2  1 0 1 0 1 0 0
3  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
4  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
5  0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

Thank you in advance and I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach uses `separate_longer_delim` from tidyr to split your text categories and then borrows a convenient dummy encoding function from `recipes` for one-hot encoding.

```r
library(recipes)
#> Loading required package: dplyr
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'recipes'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     step
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                 number=c("a,b,d","e,a","c","","k,t"))

df %>%
  separate_longer_delim(number, delim = ',') %>%
  recipe(~.) %>%
  step_dummy(number, one_hot = TRUE) %>%
  prep() %>%
  bake(new_data = NULL) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(across(everything(), max))
#> # A tibble: 5 × 9
#>      id number_X number_a number_b number_c number_d number_e number_k number_t
#>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1        0        1        1        0        1        0        0        0
#> 2     2        0        1        0        0        0        1        0        0
#> 3     3        0        0        0        1        0        0        0        0
#> 4     4        1        0        0        0        0        0        0        0
#> 5     5        0        0        0        0        0        0        1        1
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks a lot, does ```column X``` indicate what ```ID```  has no value for any of the categories?

Answer (score 0):

First extract the unique categories using base R's `strsplit`, then get the presence of each category with a `lapply` that `grepls` over each row and `as.data.frame` it:

```r
    df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                     number=c("a,b,d","e,a","c","","k,t"))
    
    
    categories <- unique(unlist(strsplit(df$number, ",")))
    
    data <- as.data.frame(lapply(categories,
           function(x) as.numeric(grepl(x, df$number))))
    names(data) <- categories

#> data
#  a b d e c k t
#1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
#2 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
#3 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
#4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
#5 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```